# how to convert a .dat file into an array in python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a problem with calculating the average value of figures in a `.dat` file.
My idea was to convert the .dat into an array and then calculate the average value with `numpy`. And here appears the problem.
The .dat file has the following structur:

```
#x #y
221.0 434.0
63.5 76.0
78.0 411.5
345.0 58.5
```

The 1st column is the x-coordinate and the 2nd is the y-coordinate. I want the average of the x- and y-coordinate but logically without the first row.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i have to admit that is was not as difficult as i thought it would be. With the numpy.loadtxt() function one can easily skip the first row using the parameter skiprows=1.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html